# Changing my tableview data source every time the view appears. Where should I do it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I declare an array at the beginning of my UITableViewController:

```
class ArchiveTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataSource: [[Book]]!
    (…)
```

And then I have a function `getDataSource()` that updates the array from a database.
My first thought was to call it at `viewWillAppear`, but it seems that the table view loads before that, so it ends up not matching the array.
I could call the function from every single table view method, but that seems a little stupid. So where is the best place to do it? It must get called every time the view appears, so viewDidLoad won't work, but it must get called before the tableview methods, so viewWillAppear won't work either. It's like I need something in between. Or is there a better way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

Edit: I should have added, that dataSource array is made up of other arrays, each representing a section in the table view. I get the number of sections and the number of rows in a section from the array too, so it must stay the same throughout the tableview methods or the app will crash, it might try to populate a row that shouldn't exist anymore, for instance.

---

Edit 4: Ah, ok, I got it! I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time looking for complicated answers. **I just had to call `getDataSource()` from *both* `viewDidLoad` *and* `viewWillAppear`, and call `tableView.reloadData()` *only* in `viewWillAppear`.**

I was trying all combinations of where to put things and with `reloadData` inside `getDataSource()` it would sometimes get called repeatedly forever until it crashed… or on other attempts I would call `getDataSource()` from `viewWillAppear` and not from `viewDidLoad`, and then it would crash the first time… anyway, I missed the most obvious combination and now I can't understand how I didn't see it before. Thank you all so much for your time.

Comment: How long does it take to get the data from the database?

Comment: Are you loading from a local database, say Core Data, or from a web service call that reads a database on the server?

Comment: @MikeTaverne It's a local database using Realm. If the problem were how long it takes it shouldn't work when I add my function to `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, right? But then it works perfectly. If I call the function from `loadView()`, though, it doesn't update the number of sections in a row right.

Comment: I will post an answer in the morning (PDT)

Comment: @MikeTaverne Alright, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. One thing I was going to suggest is to initialize dataSource to an empty array instead of nil. This way your table methods should work fine whether or not you have loaded real data. For example, numberOfSections should return 0 if you no data, which means cellForRowAtIndexPath won't be called. No crashers.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Ah, of course, that's even better than calling the function twice, I won't even have to call it at viewDidLoad then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you are showing other view controller and then going back to the one with tableView and that's why you want to update the tableView every time the view appears?

If so - it should just work the way you initially tried, if you put the getDataSource in `viewWillAppear()` and it calls `tableView.reloadData()` in the end (as you have it here in the source sample) then it will effectively show just what you have prepared for it (all the tableview methods will be called again after `reloadData()` even if they were already called before).

So I would advise debugging why it is not working when you call it from `viewWillAppear()`. **Please add some screenshots or other data of how it is not correct with this method.**

As a sidenote, if `getDataSource()` takes significant time, it may delay showing your view controller if you put it in `viewWillAppear`. In such case you'll need to do the way @Abhinav laid out for you (but you can start it from `viewWillAppear`).

**Update:** You're right, depending on how you've written `numberOfSectionsInTableView()` and `tableView(_, numberOfRowsInSection)` you may need to call `getDataSource()` also from `viewDidLoad()` or else you may crash because you're not handling empty datasets.
In that case you don't need `tableView.reloadData()` because table view methods will be called anyway, so as you noted, it's good to separate it from your `getDataSource()`.

Regarding `getDataSource()` called repeatedly until crash - it probably happened when you added `getDataSource()` in one of `UITableViewDataSource` methods (like `numberOfSectionsInTableView()`) because `reloadData()` inside `getDataSource()` would trigger this method again.

Comment: Yep, that was it! I tried `viewWillAppear()` and the problem was that after getting the rest right I didn't call it from `viewDidLoad()` too, so the first time it would crash because the tableview would need the data before `viewWillAppear()` was done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set it in `override func loadView()`.

**EDIT:** As a general practice this is how you should go it:

1. Show loading overlay on screen while table data is being fetched.
2. Once data is available:

   2.1. remove the loading overlay.

   2.2. update data source model.

   2.3. reload your table view so latest model could be picked.

Comment: Uhm, that doesn't work, weird things happen. :/ I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ok, but it's very simple data, the array is updated really fast, the problem is just where to do it. I'm playing with where to add the function and it seems that `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is the first table view method to be called, so if I call my function there everything works out. But I don't know if doing it there is the best idea, I think there should be a better option, right?

Comment: No - definitely not. Updating model in `numberOfSectionsInTableView ` is not suggested. If it is quick, my guess is you are not calling `reloadData` after your model update. In my project, I fetch my data in `loadView` and once data is available, I call `reloadData` on table view. The only thing you need to ensure here is if you are fetching data in a block, you call `reloadData` inside the block and run on main thread.

Comment: I'm calling reloadData. I had it as the last thing inside the `getDataSource` function, now I tried moving it out and calling it after the function, no difference. It's like it's looking at the updated items because it updates the section titles accordingly, but it's not getting the number of rows for each section right.

Comment: Can you please show your `getDataSource` function. Also, please print your model counts inside  `getDataSource` and call `reloadData` just after that.

Answer (score 0):

Every function needs to access your var dataSource. So that's where the call to getDataSource must go: You create an optional variable that contains either dataSource or is nil, and then you give dataSource a getter which returns that optional variable unwrapped if not nil, and calls getDataSource otherwise.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to just get the dataSource once, I want it to be updated every time the view loads. The problem is tat second and third times… I change the dataSource in another view and then I go back to this one: dataSource won't be nil, but getDataSource should still be called to update it. viewWillAppear would be perfect if only it were called before the table view methods.